# Web-Development Application with built-in WebKit Page-Preview

Tags: c#, .net, webkit

I've just finished planning for a web-dev app, and I need to build in a browser control to preview pages in. But, I won't use I.E. I want to use WebKit (this is for personal use), and I have searched all over google (and webkit's site) but am somewhat confused as to what I need to download in order to use the webkit rendering engine.

Has anybody done this before? Or anybody know what to download? I've followed the instructions on the webkit page but am left with a bunch of files that don't seem to do anything and very confused...

The project will be written in Visual C# .NET. I suppose C++ will be okay if it's not possible to use webkit with C# but I'd honestly prefer C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a .Net wrapper for Webkit (yet). You'd have to generate one somehow. One way this could be done is using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

I haven't yet d/ld the Webkit sources to see if there are SWIG binding generator scripts already included, but if there are, this would simplify things for you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) project: a `WinForms control library wrapper for WebKit written in C#'.

On another note, I'd be interested in knowing how your project goes, if you'd want to post updates on it once in a while. Good luck.